# MySQL FORCE INDEX got unexpected time cost

Tags: mysql

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hosts` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_ip_host` (`ip`,`host_name`),
  KEY `idx_host` (`host_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL version: `mysql:5.7.36.`

Here's the situation, in my project, the IP can match several hosts, I wanna get the result that matches (ip_a,host_a),(ip_b,host_b), so I use following sql:

```
select * from hosts h
     where (h.ip,h.host_name) in (("198.168.214.166","la-worker-01")... ...)
```

Actually the target set is so large, around 3000 rows, this sql will scan the complete table, and it costs 24s, I tried to use `FORCE INDEX (unq_ip_host)`, but it still cost a lot of time, almost equals scanning the whole table. Explain result:

`type: range, key: unq_ip_host, key_len: 768,rows: 8952, filtered: 50.0, extra: Using where`

Then I tried to use `FORCE INDEX (idx_host)`, and this is the result of sql explain:

`type: ALL, key: null, key_len: null,rows: 284000, filtered: 50.0, extra: Using where`

`type` is `ALL` which means it won't use the index, this is weird, when I executed the sql, `FORCE INDEX (idx_host)` costs about 4.1s, but `FORCE INDEX (idx_ip_host)` costs 24s, this is weird.

---

```
select count(distinct(ip)) from hosts; // result: 900000
select count(distinct(host_name)) from hosts; // result: 890000
```

I can improve the sql but I'm puzzled as to why the two applications of `FORCE INDEX` provide different results.

Question:

1. Why doesn't MySQL use the index, when I use `FORCE INDEX (idx_host)`?
2. Why is scanning the entire table(`FORCE INDEX (idx_host)`) faster than using index(`FORCE INDEX (idx_ip_host)`)?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to force the use of an index that isn't good when you have a perfectly working composite unique one?

Comment: @ikyuchukov I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL's docs when using `FORCE INDEX` a table scan is used if there is no way to use one of the named indexes to find rows in the table.

In this case when you use `FORCE INDEX (idx_host)` it can not find all the required information using this index and defaults to a `FULL TABLE SCAN`, the table scan query needs 4 seconds in your case.

When you use `FORCE INDEX (idx_ip_host)` it is able to get all it's required information (indexes have information regarding their PK), however due to the way your data/query is structured, using this index is inefficient hence the 24 seconds execution time.

You already mentioned that you wish to not touch the query, but it will probably be better to make a join/temporary table for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `id` for anything?  Some queries will run faster with `PRIMARY KEY(IP, host_name)`

One way to get more insight into what is going on is:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

That should show numbers like 3000.  But it sounds like it may be giving numbers like 1M.

Also, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: Thanks for your help, `id` is important for me, I need this primary key to join other tables, actually my question is not about how to make this sql faster, I've already improved this sql by combining ip and host to a new column. However, the above two questions makes me confused.

Comment: @McGrady - Are there cases of two hostnames for one IP?  Or vice versa?  `SELECT IP, COUNT(DISTINCT host_name) AS ct FROM hosts GROUP BY IP HAVING ct > 1;` and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, that's why I put the distinct result in my question.